# How solitons are related to particle physics?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, particle-physics, solitons

Recently, I read a paper about introduction to [solitons](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Soliton).

Author said that the solutions of sine-Gordon equation can be candidate for modeling elementary particles and there are some applications in quantum field theory.

I wonder how solitons can describe elementary particles and if they do, what properties of these particles are expected to be explained from studying solitons?

Comment: This might not qualify as describing _elementary_ particles, but in QCD in the limit of a large number of colors (assuming that it is confining), baryons have soliton-like properties (Witten 1979, "Baryons in the $1/N$ expansion," *Nuclear Physics B* **160**: 57-115, http://inspirehep.net/record/140391?ln=en). Baryons also show up as solitons ("Skyrmions") in a low-energy effective model of QCD in which mesons are "elementary" (https://arxiv.org/abs/hep-ph/9907554 and https://www.physics.princeton.edu/~mcdonald/examples/EP/zahed_pr_142_1_86.pdf).

Comment: Thank you for sharing information!!